# What are the specifications for the audio output?

Tags: audio

I'm having trouble locating the specifications for the audio output.  Where is this information located and what are the electrical specifications for the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but [here](http://raspberrypi.wikispaces.com/Hardware) is [what I could find](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Hardware#cite_note-faq-0):

> Audio outputs: TRS connector | 3.5 mm jack, HDMI
>
> ...
>
> S6: Audio connector: 3.5mm stereo jack (output only)

---

I also found [this forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=50751&p=392985):

> The audio output is 1v peak-to-peak maximum. It's too low-level for
> headphones (according to reports - I've not tried)
>
> Professional line-level 0dB is -or was, when first thought of - 1mW
> into 600Ω, which means 0.775v RMS or 1.09v peak, 2.18v p-p But you
> then need some headroom, and setting zero-level to 18dB below digital
> maximum means the kit should handle 10v p-p
>
> What line-level means in domestic equipment is somewhat variable.
> Also, many (all I've come across) cassette recorders have automatic
> gain control (AGC), to handle that variability.
>
> So call it line-level, and try it. You can play with the level
> somewhat on the Pi, to prevent clipping if it's too loud.
>
> You'll probably be disappointed with the result. The 3.5mm audio out
> is approx. 11-bit quality, which is probably better than the cassette
> recorder is capable of. But also, the AGC screws up the quality,
> adding noise to the quiet bits and clipping sudden peaks.

Comment: Thanks, I was after the electrical impedance, max power o/p in watts etc

Comment: @spiderplant0 I've edited in some more information.

Comment: I'm fairly sure small headphones have worked for me in the past, haven't tried big ones!