# Audio injector codec : 3.5mm jack not able to driver 2 watt speaker...why..? Raspberry pi b+

Tags: raspbian

I want to take 3.5mm jack output to speaker for a baby phone application.
But I'm not able to find any solution for connecting a small external speaker to an audio codec board.

I tried connecting 2 watt speaker but I'm not able to drive it.

Can anybody send me circuit diagram to connect class D amplifier to 3.5mm jack?

Comment: My guess is that the RPi doesn't put enough power out to properly drive a 2W speaker without an external power source.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the signal configuration in the 3.5mm audio jack:

http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-5mm-audiovideo-jack/

And more information about the electrical specification:

[What are the specifications for the audio output?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9831/what-are-the-specifications-for-the-audio-output)